# Are there any mechanical differences between how tradition mages and technocratic mages use magick?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, mage-20th-anniversary

I haven't been able to find anything to indicate mechanical differences between the two(Though Technocrats seem to lean more heavily on gadget usage rather than spontaneous magic.) but I seem to recall that there were some differences.

TLDR: What are the mechanical differences between tradition based magick and technocratic magick?

Comment: I am going to be honest. I was expecting to have to refuse edits changing magick to magic and I am pleasantly surprised by the lack of said edits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Technocrats have a mix of advantages and disadvantages compared to other Mages.

The first, and most obvious, difference between Technocrats and other Mages is that they have access to the variant Technocratic Spheres - they can choose to learn Dimensional Science instead of Spirit, Primal Utility instead of Prime, and Data instead of Correspondence. These aren't mandatory - many Void Engineers learn Correspondence rather than Data, for instance, since the former is a lot more useful in both outer space and alternate dimensions - but Technocrats simply have options that other Mages don't.

Secondly, when they have access to Technocratic manufacturing facilities, they can manufacture Devices and other permanent Wonders without needing to invest a point of permament Willpower into each Wonder. This is mentioned in the Wonder-creation chapter of the Book of Secrets.

Thirdly, they are incapable of transcending the use of Tools in their Foci like other Mages; this is mentioned in the chapter on Foci in the M20 corebook. A possible exception is if they have taken the Psychic Practice from M20 Book of Secrets as one of the three Practices in their Focus; it says in the listing of that Practice that technomancers who have it can transcend Tools when working with that Practice as though they were mystic Mages, but whether or not that applies to Technocrats or just non-Technocratic technomages is ambiguous.

It should be pointed out, however, that Technocrats *are* fully capable of the full breadth of spontaneous magick granted by their Spheres with the use of their Practices and Tools - whether that is them unlocking prototype functionality in their equipment, building prototype devices, utilising advanced techniques from their martial arts training, running an app on their cell phone, etc. They're not reliant on premade Gadgets and Devices; they just can't cast Magick without one of their Tools.

Finally, Technocrats have access to certain Backgrounds that non-Technocrats don't have access to, but that's more a function of their organisation and its resources than of their magick. Similarly, some of their game traits have different names, but that's simply a matter of their culture giving different names to the same game-mechanical traits - a Mage's magical energy works just the same regardless of whether it's called Quintessence, Primal Energy, or Qi.